# Inline block elements don't vertically align with ellipsis overflow

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am displaying `label` , `input` , and `div` elements inline, expecting them to align vertically, which works initially.

However, when I attempt to allow the `div`'s contents to overflow with an ellipsis, they do not vertically align anymore

**Note:** This was observed in Chrome 46.02490.86

```css
p {color:red;}
input,
label,
div {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
}
.longdesc {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div>Short</div>
<hr />
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div class='longdesc'>Longer Description</div>
<p>
    In the second example "Long" is higher up
</p>
```

How can I achieve the overflow effect without messing up the vertical alignment?

Comment: Isn't vertical alignment up and down? Horizontal alignment is left and right?  `inline-block` is to display an element left to right. `block` is to display elements up and down flow (stacked on top of each other vertical in other words) I see, you want the content to align, ok.

Comment: by vertical alignment I meant having the text inline, nothing higher or lower. perhaps my word choice wasn't the best

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `inline-block` elements:

```css
p {color:red;}
input,
label,
div {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
}
.longdesc {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div>Short</div>
<hr />
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div class='longdesc'>Longer Description</div>
<p>
    In the second example "Long" is higher up
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept as answer.-  Strange, `vertical-align: top, middle, bottom` all produced the same results.

Comment: @EricPhillips - that's because you have a single line, so top middle and bottom are the same. Try that with multiple lines to see the difference.

Comment: Single line or same height of elements?)

Comment: Just set height for your `input` eg 100px to see difference. Now your all elements have same height ~18px

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where is your vertical alignment in css?
In default `vertical-align` has property `baseline`, if you want to center use `vertical-align: middle`

```css
p {color:red;}
input,
label,
div {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
}
.longdesc {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div>Short</div>
<hr />
<label>Name:</label>
<input type='text' value='James'>
<label>Desc:</label>
<div class='longdesc'>Longer Description</div>
<p>
    In the second example "Long" is not higher up :)
</p>
```

Comment: Right, I didn't specify because I didnt anticipate having to define a vertical align as they lined up before implementing the overflow ellipsis chunk of code